# Export to csv not working on Safari with Alasql JavaScript library with XLSX.js. - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, export-to-csv, alasql

I want to export table data in csv format in my app. I have used Alasql library with XLSX.js. It works fine with all modern browsers(Chrome, Firefox ..) not on Safari.

Comment: Unfortunately we can not find any solution to save files in  Safari. If you find a solution/library, which saves data to Safari 9 (let's call it ```saveSafari()```, then you can generate XLSX file in memory and then save it to the disk:
   ```saveSafari(alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX({headers:true}) FROM ?',[$scope.data]));```

(Disclaimer: I the author of AlaSQL)