# Export to CSV not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, csv, safari

I am working on a requirement where I need to export data into CSV file and download it. It has to work on safari browser. I read many links on net that download into CSV won't work in Safari. I came across a js fiddle 
 which works in chrome but not in safari. I also came across the link  "[Export to csv not working on Safari with Alasql JavaScript library with XLSX.js. - Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845820/export-to-csv-not-working-on-safari-with-alasql-javascript-library-with-xlsx-js)" where writer of AlaSql is informing that it won't work in Safari.  I followed the steps given in http://www.123contactform.com/docs/i-cannot-download-csv-file-on-safari-what-to-do/ but it also didn't turned the things.

I would like to know why this feature won't work in safari. Is there any workaround to implement this feature in safari?

EDIT :- I saw in ngmodules official site that they have mentioned, ng-csv won't work in Safari. http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-csv . But it is updated 12 months ago. Is this holds good for today also?